How can I find volume of polyhedron so that Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] <= 6$ && Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z - 2] <= 6?
I am trying find volume  of the polyhedron so that
$|x| + |y| + |z| \leqslant 6$ and $|x| + |y| + |z-2| \leqslant 6$.
 RegionPlot3D[{Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] <= 6 && 
   Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z - 2] <= 6}, {x, -8, 8}, {y, -10, 
  10}, {z, -6, 6}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]  


I change $z$
 RegionPlot3D[{Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] <= 6 && 
   Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z - 2] <= 6}, {x, -8, 8}, {y, -10, 
  10}, {z, -6, 4}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]


How can I tell Mathematica find volume of polyhedrons?

I am not sure If this is what you're asking, but if you use RegionPlot3D instead of RegionPlot, you can see the region that satisfies your predicates (and  using Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] <= 6 && Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z - 2] <= 6 instead of {Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] <= 6, Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z - 2] <= 6} which would plot two separate regions

reg = ImplicitRegion[{Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] <= 6, 
     Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z - 2] <= 6}, {x, y, z}];
reg // Volume


500/3

Another way to draw such region.
Clear["Global`*"]; 
reg1 = 
 ImplicitRegion[{Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] <= 6}, {x, y, z}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[{Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z - 2] <= 6}, {x, y, 
    z}];
reg3 = Octahedron[6 Sqrt[2]];
reg4 = Octahedron[{0, 0, 2}, 6 Sqrt[2]]
RegionEqual[reg1, reg3]
RegionEqual[reg2, reg4]


True.


True.

reg = RegionIntersection[reg3, reg4];
oct = Octahedron[{0, 0, 1}, 5 Sqrt[2]];
RegionEqual[oct, reg]
Graphics3D[{reg, oct}]
{reg // Volume, oct // Volume}


True.


